# do browser default if no keydown shortcut

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

in my usercontrol I overrided the keydown , such that I check for example

```
       if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.E)
       {

       }
```

but I noticed that the browser main shortcuts like Ctrl+P not work , any idea how to fix that 
also in internet explorer if I check for ctrl+e in the keydown to do certain task, the shortcut do what the browser shortcut should do

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned browser, i assumed you are asking for javascript. Please consider shortcut.js from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/
Read: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/#keys

```
Example:
shortcut.add("Down",function() {
    alert("keydown!");
});

//Remove the shortcut
shortcut.remove("Down");
```